# Can I withdraw a paper from IEEE conference after signing the copyright form?

Tags: conference, copyright, graphics, ieee

I have submitted a manuscript using figures from google. I have cited the web pages from where I have found the figures in my article. The figures are actually figures of apparatus. Later I learnt from IEEE website that IEEE discourages usage of figures from web pages without prior permission which I have not taken. But I have submitted the paper and copyright form to IEEE conference. As the date for camera ready and pdfxpress is already over I can't edit my manuscript now as told by the conference chair.

What should I do now? How may I withdraw it from here and publish it in other place? Is it possible to withdraw after signing copyright? Is it worth requesting the conference chair to open the pdfxress for few minutes so that I may upload my new manuscript there? Please help me.

Comment: Have you registered the paper for presentation? If yes, you can not. Else you can.

Comment: "IEEE discourages usage of figures from web pages without prior permission which I have not taken." - _Any_ reputable publisher will require you to have a license/permission if you use images that you don't own the copyright to.

Comment: I have not registered yet. But have signed the copyright.

Comment: I believe your situation falls under fair use, see http://libguides.mit.edu/usingimages ... It is not considered good practice to use images the way you have, but technically it is not a problem. I don't think you should, or need to, retract your paper because of it.

Comment: @Arnfinn IANAL, but given that IEEE is a for-profit entity who sells technical papers I very much doubt that this is a case of fair use.

Comment: @xLeitix The OP has taken pictures of apparatus from the Web; as far as I can understand, that would be product photos. The OP could have taken similar, almost identical, pictures using a good camera. I can't possibly see how using product photos would have any market effect for the company who commissioned these photos for marketing purposes, or benefit IEEE economically in any way... I see this all the time in presentations and sometimes papers.

Answer (score 4):

Email the programme chair and ask them how they would like you to proceed.  It is possible that they will still allow you to make changes to the paper, even at a late stage (provided it doesn't substantially affect the content).  If nothing else, they can ask the IEEE for advice, this is unlikely to be the first time this has happened, so there may be a standard answer already.